# Java Android How to get HTTPUrlConnection (POST) response code and message in the Exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

This is my situation. I am calling the web authentication API with POST message. Upon success, it returns a token. Otherwise, it returns error message (json) specifying reasons (eg: `"incorrect password", "account lock", etc`), with response code `400, etc`.

Sample error viewed from browser:

[image]

So, I manage to **call, get and return** the success message, but not when there is an error. Here's the pseudo code (I omit the redundant part. Basically focus on the 'catch' scope):

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null; //Must define outside as null?
    try {
        ...
        byte[] postDataBytes = ...

        URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        ...
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
        String response = sb.toString(); // Yeah I got this
        return response;
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        //the variable ex doesn't tell anything about the response code
        //neither the response message

        //so i access the conn to get
        //
        try {
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            return "code: " + responseCode; //somehow this line just doesn't work!
        }
        catch (Exception ex2){
        }
    }
```

To elaborate a bit, the `IOException` doesn't tell anything about the response. So I access the `HttpURLConnection` variable.

The 
`conn.getResponseCode() does return 400`,

`conn.getResponseMessage() does return "Bad Request"`, but NOT the error json message from server.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I just want to know, what is the correct way to get the response code/message during Exception/error.

Comment: You can use [getErrorStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream()) of HttpURLConnection.

Comment: There will not be a catch as a json text is returned as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getErrorStream()` of `HttpUrlConnection` is probably what you are looking for.

```
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8"));

    // Do you response parsing here.
```

Comment: You should use readLine() instead of calling a function for every char.